# AcroJS form field button works only once

Tags: javascript, adobe, acrobat

I've only found in-browser JS solutions, and this is for a standalone PDF file.  The button is located at the end of a multi-page PDF document and has the following "Mouse Up" script:

```
var pp = this.getPrintParams();
pp.interactive = pp.constants.interactionLevel.silent;
pp.DuplexType = pp.constants.duplexTypes.DuplexFlipLongEdge;
this.print(pp);
this.resetForm();
this.pageNum=0;
app.alert("Hooray! Please let the Student Employment assistant know that you're done.",4);
```

It works fine if the user selects "OK" to print, but if they cancel and then try to click the button again, nothing happens. The user has to close the document and then reopen it, but that of course erases all the fields they had filled out.

Comment: Where does the user select OK to print? Because of the "silent" interaction level, there won't be any print dialog appearing.

Comment: Well strangely enough, Adobe Acrobat will still pop up a print dialogue that says "This document is trying to print. Do you want to allow this?"  If the user doesn't select "Yes", then the above problem will occur.

Comment: Ah, got it. This is an alert because of security behavior in Acrobat. You might have a look at the Acrobat JavaScript documentation about privileged actions. Alternatively, you might deactivate silent printing and let the user see and use the Print dialog.

Comment: Ha, I actually included the silent interaction level _because_ I didn't want the user to have to bother with the print dialog! But it sounds like I should investigate privileged actions to see if there's something that's preventing the script from being triggered more than once.